# Calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How to  Calculate and display the difference between two dates using PHP? i had try some of methods but i couldn't execute perfectly. anyone can help me

```
  S/N  | Event          | Duration 
 ----- | -------------  | ------------ 
  01   | Trip- Bangkok  | 2016-11-08 to 2016-11-20
  02   | Trip-New York  | 2016-12-01 to 2016-12-17
```

but i would like to display like this

```
  S/N  | Event          | Duration days
 ----- | -------------  | ------------ 
  01   | Trip- Bangkok  | 12 days
  02   | Trip-New York  | 17 days
```

My database

```html
 <table border="1" width="920px" align="center" cellpadding="3" class="mytable" cellspacing="0" >
        <tr>
            <th>S/N</th>
            <th>Event</th> 
            <th>Duration</th>
        </tr>
  
       <?php
   $key="";
 if(isset($_POST['searchtxt']))
  $key=$_POST['searchtxt'];
 
 if($key !="")
  $sql_sel=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM trip_tbl NATURAL JOIN info_tbl WHERE info_name  like '%$key%' or event like '%$key%'");
 else
        $sql_sel=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info_tbl  NATURAL JOIN trip_tbl");
  
    $i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel)){
    $i++;
    $color=($i%2==0)?"lightblue":"white";
    ?>
      <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $color?>">
       <!-- <tr><br><?php echo  $i;?></br></tr> -->
         <td><p align ="center"><?php echo $i;?></p></td>
            <td><font size="4px"><?php echo $row['event'];?></font></td>   
   <td><font size="4px"><?php echo $row['departure']." to ".$row['arrived'];?></font></td>
   
            </tr>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
 <tr></tr>
```

:- 
I've used DATEDIFF but it's doesn't work out

Comment: what is the type of `Duration` field in table?

Comment: my db : id (int), event (varchar), departure(date), arrived(date)

Answer (score 1):

If you have PHP version > 5.3 then you can calculate with this.

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2016-11-08");
$date2 = new DateTime("2016-11-20");

$diff = $date2->diff($date1)->format("%d");
echo $diff;
```

**$diff will print your exact days.**

Comment: nope it's not :( may be i made mistake but i couldn't find it, anyway thank a lot for your help

Comment: I have done with this code. you can check it in http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Also try with %d. 
May be it will help you.

Comment: I have ran same code in http://phpfiddle.org/ Try paste that code and see the output.

Comment: Check my output https://www.screencast.com/t/hwD6pDtkYa